# Android: Spinner displaying contents from web service

Tags: android, user-interface, android-asynctask, spinner

I want to make such thing:

The main goal is to display spinner contents loaded from some web service.

User clicks on spinner - adapter should show some text, like "loading...". And when it finally be loaded - it should replace existing adapter in spinner with loaded contents.

What did I do: I've made a **spinner** and **onTouchListener** for it. In Listener I am launching **asyncTask**, which downloads data from web service. In **onPostExecute** of **asyncTask** I am trying actually to replace spinners adapter and do **spinner.performClick()**. But in fact, user is seeing 2 adapters simultaneously - initial one ("Loading...") and the new one, which was shown by **spinner.performClick()**.

Are there any better ideas how can be done initial task or how I can show only one adapter?

Here is some code I use:

```
private class CountryRegionCity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONArray> {
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Getting contents from web service            
        {...}
        return someJSONArray;
    }

        protected void onPostExecute (JSONArray jsonArray) {

        ArrayList<String> countryNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        //Filling here countryNames based on jsonArray
        {...}

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countryNames);

        mCountrySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        mCountrySpinner.performClick();
    }
}

public View onCreateDialogView() {

    ArrayAdapter<String> countryArrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String> (context(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[] {"Loading..."});
    mCountrySpinner.setAdapter(countryArrayAdapter);

    mCountrySpinner.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {      
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                CountryRegionCity getCountries = new CountryRegionCity();
                getCountries.execute("countries");
                return false;
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can user `notifyDataSetChanged()` method of Spinner control to show the change in adapter data.